# Dynamic array of uniforms (GLSL OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, glsl

In a shader (using OpenGL ES 2.0) I want to have an array with a dynamic size.

I can declare an array with fixed size:

```
uniform vec2 vertexPositions[4];
```

But now I want to set the size dynamic to the number of points, which I will pass.

I thought about making a string replacement in the shader source before compiling it, but than I have to compile it everytime I draw a different element. That seems to be CPU-intensive.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach would be to size the uniform array to the maximum number of elements you expect to use, and then only update the subset of it that you're actually using. You can then pass in the effective size of the array as a separate uniform.

```
uniform vec2 arr[MAX_SIZE];
uniform int arr_size;
```

Comment: I aslo thought about this solution, but I thought it might be too storage-hungry?

Comment: It also throws a exception when compiling the shader: `error C1307: non constant expression for array size`

Comment: Right, you're going to need the maximum amount of storage either way--you don't save anything by only using it for part of the frame.

Comment: MAX_SIZE needs to be a constant--either a literal (like 512), a const, or a #define. (i.e. you can't define an array size in terms of another uniform.)

Comment: is it possible that the max size for an array is 255?